# summarizing and spreading a dataset

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset named temp:

```
> >temp
# A tibble: 9 x 3
     ID PainScore PainScoreOrder
  <int>     <int>          <chr>
1     1         4          First
2     1         2         Middle
3     1         3         Middle
4     1         3           Last
5     2         9          First
6     2         8           Last
7     3         7          First
8     3         4         Middle
9     3         5           Last
```

I'm trying to create a summary table that has only one row per ID and a separate column for PainScore values where PainScoreOrder = "First" and an additional column for PainScore values where PainScoreOrder = "Last". I want to ignore values where PainScoreOrder = "Middle". What I want should look like this:

```
> temp2
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     ID First  Last
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4     3
2     2     9     8
3     3     7     5
```

I'm trying to do this in dplyr but am open to any other solution.

I'm not looking for the code to do this, but rather a nudge in the right direction. I can't even figure out what to search for to try and figure this out.

I've tried various approaches using summarise without success. I sort of think the answer is with a spread command but, when I try the following code:

```
> temp %>%
   spread(PainScoreOrder, PainScore, -ID)
```

I get the following error code:

> Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (2, 3)

I apologize for asking such a vague question but I feel like if I knew enough to be more specific I'd know how to solve my problem. Again, I just need a suggestion of what to look for.

Thanks for being gentle with me on my first question here.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
df %>%
  filter(PainScoreOrder != "Middle") %>%
  spread(key = PainScoreOrder, value = PainScore)
```

I assume that that you only have one observation of `First` and `Last` in each group.

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick. It also let's me know spread is what I need to go study. I really appreciate the help!